# how do I maintain grid layout when added content

Tags: html, css

I want to maintain grid layout and I also use flexbox for items because I want to section the title and the content. However the layout changes to fit the content. For example if I put Lorem in side-bar, the bar will expand. How do I fix this, if I want the layout to be the same ratio regardless of the content inside the item?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');


.grid-container{
    display: grid;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    gap: 20px;
    background-color: wheat;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "side-bar main main ad" 
    "side-bar main main ad"
    "side-bar main main ad"
    "side-bar footer footer ad"
    ;
    text-align: center;
    
}

p{
    text-align: start;
}

.grid-container > div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    
}


.side-bar{
    grid-area: side-bar;
    
    
}

.main{
    grid-area: main;
   
}

.ad{
    grid-area: ad;
   
}

.footer{
    grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Grid and Flexbox</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="canvas.css"/> 
</head>
<body>

<!-- GRID BOXES-->
<div class="grid-container"> 
    <div class="side-bar">  
        <div> Grid title 1</div>
        <div><p>  </p></div>
    
    </div>
    <div class="main">      Grid title 2</div>
    <div class="footer">    Grid title 3</div>
    <div class="ad">        Grid title 4
        <div><p></p></div>
    </div>
</div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the column size otherwise the auto width will get used which depend on the content:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  gap: 20px;
  background-color: wheat;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* ADDED */
  grid-template-areas: 
   "side-bar main main ad" 
   "side-bar main main ad" 
   "side-bar main main ad"
   "side-bar footer footer ad";
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: start;
}

.grid-container>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.side-bar {
  grid-area: side-bar;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
}

.ad {
  grid-area: ad;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="side-bar">
      <div> Grid title 1</div>
      <div>
        <p> </p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="main"> Grid title 2</div>
    <div class="footer"> Grid title 3</div>
    <div class="ad"> Grid title 4
      <div>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```